# Spark-Submit with a Pyspark file.

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to test a program TensorflowOnSpark in cluster. I think I am using a wrong spark-submit command. Please look below

I tried to submit a job as shown

```
~]$ spark-submit mnistOnSpark.py --cluster_size 10
```

The above job runs successfully, but runs on a single node, both the Executor and the driver are on the **same machine**. But I need to the job to run on multiple nodes.So I tried the below command

```
~]$ spark-submit --master yarn-cluster mnistOnSpark.py --cluster_size 10
```

Is it the right command I should use to submit a job, Or anything else I should learn.

--cluster_size is the command line argument for mnistOnSpark.py code.

Answer (score 4):

If you are running job on yarn cluster, you can run following command:

```
spark-submit --master yarn --jars <comma-separated-jars> --conf <spark-properties> --name <job_name> <python_file> <argument 1> <argument 2>
```

eg:

```
spark-submit --master yarn --jars example.jar --conf spark.executor.instances=10 --name example_job example.py arg1 arg2
```

For `mnistOnSpark.py` you should pass arguments as mentioned in the command above.

spark submit thinks that you are trying to pass `--cluster_mode` to spark job.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --num-executors 10 --executors-cores 2 mnistOnSpark.py
```

Comment: My question , How come only this .py file alone is enough mnistOnSpark.py, In scala we use to give jar file that contains all scala files, but here in phython only one .py file , is that correct